# Linq, datatable and shared properties

Tags: linq, properties, datatable, shared

I am trying to do this linq query but I am getting the "EmpCritGID cannot be initialized because it is shared" error while coding. What is the correct way to query a datatable and stuff the values in an existing class with shared properties for use in vb.net code behind?

```
    If CriteriaFlags.CritOrgFlag AndAlso lblOrgName.Text.Equals(String.Empty) Then 
        lblOrgName.Text = "Need Org Assigned" 
        lblOrgName.ForeColor = redColor 
        lblOrgName.BackColor = yellowColor 
    End If 

    Dim result = From c In EmployeeJobCriteria.AsEnumerable() 
        Where c.Field(Of Integer)("EmpCritGID").Equals(intEmpCritGID) 
        Select New EmployeeCriteria.CriteriaFlags _ 
        With {.EmpCritGID = c.Field(Of Integer)("EmpCritGID"), _ 
        .EmpJobFID = c.Field(Of Integer)("EmpJobFID"), _ 
        .CritFID = c.Field(Of Integer)("CritFID"), _ 
        .NodeGID = c.Field(Of Integer)("NodeGID"), _ 
        .CritOrgFlag = c.Field(Of Boolean)("CritOrgFlag"), _ 
        .CritWeightFlag = c.Field(Of Boolean)("CritWeightFlag"), _ 
        .CritOppFlag = c.Field(Of Boolean)("CritOppFlag"), _ 
        .CritActFlag = c.Field(Of Boolean)("CritActFlag")} 

    Namespace Objective 

        Public Class EmployeeCriteria 

             Public Class CriteriaFlags 

                Public Shared EmpCritGID As Integer 
                Public Shared EmpJobFID As Integer 
                Public Shared CritFID As Integer 
                Public Shared NodeGID As Integer 
                Public Shared CritOrgFlag As Boolean 
                Public Shared ShareCritPmtFlag As Boolean 
                Public Shared CritWeightFlag As Boolean 
                Public Shared CritOppFlag As Boolean 
                Public Shared CritActFlag As Boolean 

            End Class 

        End Class 

    End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Shared` keyword.

```
Public Class CriteriaFlags 

    Public EmpCritGID As Integer 
    Public EmpJobFID As Integer 
    Public CritFID As Integer 
    Public NodeGID As Integer 
    Public CritOrgFlag As Boolean 
    Public ShareCritPmtFlag As Boolean 
    Public CritWeightFlag As Boolean 
    Public CritOppFlag As Boolean 
    Public CritActFlag As Boolean 

End Class
```

It makes no sense to initialize objects by setting a shared(static) variable or property. They would share all values anyway.

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/sharedinstance.htm

Comment: So, I'm assuming you would initialize the class in the row_databound function where I need it?

Comment: Also, would I use the initialized variable say objEmpCritFlag as New EmployeeCriteria.CriteriaFlags and use objEmpCritFlag inside the LINQ?

Comment: I don't know where you need it and that doesn't matter at all. You should add the initialization into the select of the linq query(where it is already). When you execute the query the `CriteriaFlags` objects will be created and initialized. Where you use the variables depends on the context. You can chain linq queries, call ToList or ToArray somewhere, use `For Each` or use it as DataSource for something. But that is out of scope of this question. Remember to accept/upvote  answers if they wer helpful. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work